# Bid-rent function in The Microgeography of Housing Supply

Tags: profit-maximization, profits

I came across the paper "The Microgeography of Housing Supply" (Baum-Snow, 2020)(https://luhan2.weebly.com/uploads/9/6/0/8/96080580/housing_supply_julyb2020.pdf) and I must admit that I do not know how to solve the bid-rent function in it as described in the screenshot attached. When I put the optimal living area A=A(P) and the marginal price P=dC(A)/dA, I do not end up with the result implied by the paper. Are they using a particular theorem here?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's just algebraic rearrangement. Below I suppress the subscripts and the argument of $A$:

Take the first term on the RHS of profit,
\begin{align}
PA&=\frac{\mathrm dC(A)}{\mathrm dA}\cdot A\\
&=\frac{C(A)}{C(A)}\cdot\frac{\mathrm dC(A)}{\mathrm dA}\cdot A\\
&=C(A)\frac{\mathrm dC(A)}{C(A)}\cdot\frac{A}{\mathrm dA}\\
&=C(A)\cdot \mathrm d\ln C(A)\cdot\frac{1}{\mathrm d\ln A}
\end{align}
The rest should be straightforward.